# .php Extension Remove not Wokring

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on the site is www.pinkdropwellness.com.

At the moment I am working on trying to remove the .php extension from the URLs in my site.

No matter whose code I try, it doesn't work on my site. When I remove .php from my link's href it will always send me to a page not found.

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/? /$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+).php$ /$1/ [R]
```

I have tried all sorts of different recommended codes, and no matter what I try I either get redirected to /public_html/link, or /link which both are error pages. Even when I leave link.php as the href, it shows up as an error page. I feel like I am missing something simple here!

EDIT:

Here is my index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Pink Drop Wellness Homepage">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Pink,Drop,Wellness,Fertility,Awareness,Essential,Oils,Blog">
    <meta name="author" content="Lucy Bowe">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <img id="logo" src="/images/PinkDrop.png" alt="Pink Drop Wellness">
    <img id="tree" src="/images/Tree.png" alt="Tree" usemap="#links">

    <map name="links">
       <area
         shape="poly"
         name="blog"
         coords="445,105,432,123,418,132,402,132,386,136,385,156,417,168,437,185,475,208,510,197,531,167,527,141,496,106"
         href="/blog"
         alt="Blog"
        />
        <area
          shape="poly"
          name="fertilityawareness"
          coords="138,450,149,443,167,441,186,441,199,447,208,458,228,466,243,477,256,477,270,483,302,480,325,475,349,472,371,457,383,443,391,427,373,398,345,373,310,347,268,334,218,348,194,377,141,436,169"
          href="/fertilityawareness"
          alt="Fertility Awareness"
         />
         <area
           shape="poly"
           name="essentialoils"
           coords="787,490,753,498,719,523,671,553,634,566,593,541,545,487,540,432,570,407,606,403,653,420"
           href="/essentialoils"
           alt="Essential Oils"
          />
    </map>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
    <script>
      var image = $('#tree');

      image.mapster({
        mapKey: 'name',
        listKey: 'name',
        clickNavigate: true,
        isSelectable: false,
        areas: [
          {
            key: "blog",
            fillColor: "5679c7",
          },
          {
            key: "essentialoils",
            fillColor: "638a69",
          },
          {
            key: "fertilityawareness",
            fillColor: "785fc2",
          }
        ]
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

It will remove the .php extension .

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

use the link like

```
<a href="contact">contact</a>
```

In the Url, it will display like
 `domain.com/contact`

Comment: This code made it so that my home page did not work. It seems the broken line is RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]. However when I remove it and I click on one of my links it directs me to http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/public_html/link/ instead of http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/link/

Comment: Thank you! That made it so that the homepage works but it is still directing me to http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/public_html/blog/. Feel free to try it out

Comment: Can you share your code or any link where I can check your code?

Comment: @TurtleBo, on which link you clicked? Can you share that link?

Comment: I added the code for my index page to the main post. Also feel free to checkout the webpage pinkdropwellness.com

Comment: I checked all the link and all are working perfectly. http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/blog, http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/essentialoils http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/fertilityawareness        I think you have to clear the history and than check it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/$    index.php    [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.akshadainfosystem.com
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

http://www.akshadainfosystem.com/profile original url http://www.akshadainfosystem.com/profile.php just do not add .php extension to your link just as I did.

Comment: It was redirecting me to your page at first. RewriteRule ^/$    index.php    [L] was making it so my index page wouldn't load. When I erased the error redirect and the index rewrite and I click my link it sends me to http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/public_html/blog/

Comment: I checked http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/index http://www.pinkdropwellness.com/index.php with both your website is working  fine You need to clear your browser cache or try in other browser

Comment: Yes. They're working fine now that I changed some things. But it still doesn't remove the .php extension